# watir (6.2.1) does not support drag and drop anymore?

Tags: selenium-webdriver, watir

Unable to perform drag and drop (we don't often use drag_and_drop_on so I don't remember the last time this method worked; but I know for a fact that it used to work with the previous watir-webdriver versions)

Current config:

- watir (6.2.1)
- selenium-webdriver (3.3.0)
- IE11 / Chrome56 / FF52

Example Code Below (with URL):

```
    irb(main):037:0> browser.url
    => "http://the-internet.herokuapp.com/drag_and_drop"
    irb(main):038:0> a.flash
    => #<Watir::Div: located: true; {:id=>"column-a", :tag_name=>"div"}>
    irb(main):039:0> b.flash
    => #<Watir::Div: located: true; {:id=>"column-b", :tag_name=>"div"}>
    irb(main):040:0> a.drag_and_drop_on b
    => nil
    irb(main):041:0> a.drag_and_drop_on b
    => nil
```

Comment: For Chromedriver, this is reported in [Bug 841](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/chromedriver/issues/detail?id=841#c72) with the same test case in comment 67. I'm not sure about the other drivers.